# Returning Id from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, listbox

I have two methods in my WCF, one to populate my `ListBox` and the other one to delete my selected `ListBox` items.

My issue is when I run my Delete method the Data shows null, there is also no errors or exceptions.

The coding runs smoothly but nothing changes and the Selected Item stays in the list box.

**WPF**

```
private void bnFeedDel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    using (TruckServiceClient service = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        service.DelFeedAsync(new FeedView
            {
                Id = lbFeed.SelectedIndex
            });
    }
}

public async Task LoadFeeds()
{

    TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient();

    try 
    {           
        List<ClientItems> feeditems = new List<ClientItems>();

        foreach (var item in await TSC.GetFeedAsync())
        {
            feeditems.Add(new ClientItems
                {
                    FId = item.Id,
                    FTitle = item.Title,
                    FContent = item.Content
                });
        }

        lbFeed.ItemsSource = (feeditems.ToArray());
        lbFeed.DisplayMemberPath = "FTitle";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**WCF**

```
public void DelFeed(FeedView feedview)
{

    using (var result = new TruckDb())
    {
        var t = new Feed
            {
                Id = feedview.Id,
                Title = feedview.Title,
                Content = feedview.Content
            };
        result.Feed.Remove(t);
        result.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is all kinda still new to me so any comments/suggestions for my coding would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the call to your WCF service, you're passing in a new instance of `FeedView`, with only the `Id` property set:

```
service.DelFeedAsync(new FeedView { Id = lbFeed.SelectedIndex });
```

So when the the service method runs, both `Title` and `Content` do not have values to be set (assuming they're both strings, they'll be null or empty strings):

```
var t = new Feed {
        Id = feedview.Id,
        Title = feedview.Title,
        Content = feedview.Content};
```

When you call `result.Feed.Remove(t);`, nothing is removed because there's no matching item to remove.

Additional note:  using `using` with WCF Service Clients is against best practices:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx